# How do I position a radio button correctly?

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/BD8j2/

I am trying to put a radio button to the right of the arrow picture, but it always keeps going someplace else for some reason. I want it between the arrow and the word Masculino.

I also don't want this button to really record anything, it's just there for aesthetic purposes. But I want when someone click on this box for the radio button to fill and then to link to another page.

Is this possible to do? For the whole box to be the link? I was thinking of wrappign the whole div in a `<a href>` which I think would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BD8j2/8/.

(The HTML in the first version of this post is invalid (`input` inside `a`), and it is not cross-browser compatible, so I have replaced it with a JavaScript example.)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="answers">
    <form>
        <label class="links">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
            <a href="http://w3.org">Masculino</a>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="answers">
    <form>
        <label class="links">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
            <a href="http://w3.org">Femenino</a>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function init() {
    var link_elems = getElementsByClass('links');
    for(var i = 0; i < link_elems.length; i++) {
        addEvent(link_elems[i], 'click', goToLink);
    }
}
function goToLink(e) {
    if(e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else if(typeof e.cancelBubble != 'undefined') {
        e.cancelBubble();
    }
    e.currentTarget.children[0].checked = true;
    window.location = e.currentTarget.children[1].href;
}
function addEvent(elem, event, handler) {
    if(elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    } else if(elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    } else {
        elem['on' + event] = handler;
    }
}
function getElementsByClass(className) {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName) {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    } else if(document.all) {
        var everything = document.all;
        var all_length = everything.length;
        var matches = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < all_length; i++) {
            if(everything[i].className == className) {
                matches[matches.length] = everything[i];
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }
    return false;
}
addEvent(window, 'load', init);
```

**CSS:**

```
.answers {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: url('http://fortmovies.com/brazil/arrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
}
.answers label {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 75px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold
}
.answers input {
    margin-right: 5px
}
```

In the previous version, the JavaScript required putting the link names and targets in two arrays, now I have made it automatic.

Comment: You're welcome. `:-)` With this example, JavaScript is not required.

Comment: @Musa Hrm... I see now... Also, just noticed it is invalid. JS would be the best solution, otherwise removing the `option` would be the best option.

Comment: ah, the JS is over my head.. i think I might just make the whole buttons in photoshop just to avoid this headache lol

Comment: @sab - It's actually quite easy in JavaScript, I will post an example.

Comment: @sab - I have posted the example.

Comment: @sab - I have made it automatic (you don't have to worry about updating the JavaScript when you add to / update the HTML). See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/XEk5d/2/, the clicking part to go to another page would require JavaScript.

CSS

```css
#answers {
    width:220px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#arrowcenter {
    width:71px;
    height:31px;
    background-image:url('http://fortmovies.com/brazil/arrow.png');
    background-position:0 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle;
} 

#answerstext {
    background-position:0 50%;
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form{
    display:inline-block;
}
input{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="answers">
    <div id="arrowcenter"></div>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
        <div id="answerstext">Masculino</div>
    </form>
</div><!-- end grayAnswer -->?
```

Comment: dang i have to javascript? dammmit

Comment: Using `label`s would be better.